# Can you write applications for the Zune HD?

Tags: zune-hd

I know you can write applications for the Zune, but what about the Zune HD?

Comment: Given the marketshare, completing with iPods - why bother?

Comment: because its there... sitting on my doorstep... waiting for me... oh and i don't want to program in objective c

Comment: App store is already chock a block with every application you can think of.  HD is wide open.  BRB, developing fart app for the HD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/09/xna-game-studio-31-zune-extensions.html

yes.  And, while XNA targets gaming, normal apps are usually less complex, so IMHO there's nothing that says you won't be able to deliver normal apps as well as games that target the HD.

Mine's already shipped.

Answer (score 6):

After much research on Google I have determined that the Zune HD is likely, but not officially confirmed, to have support for XNA. If it does have support for XNA, you will be able to create apps for it, although those apps will likely be games as XNA is primarily a game development framework.

UPDATE: XNA Studios just added Zine HD support. So yes, you can at least make games for Zune HD as well as any other app you can make with XNA.

Comment: Update: XNA has been dead for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sound like it -- see [here](http://tech.blorge.com/Structure:%20/2009/09/15/zune-hd-launches-with-promises-of-twitter-and-facebook-apps/):

> Zune HD will indeed be getting
>   applications, but at this time
>   Microsoft is planning to keep the
>   development in-house.  In those
>   situations where they do want to work
>   with a third-party developer, it will
>   be a close relationship with the
>   Redmond,WA-based software giant.  In
>   other words, you won’t be seeing the
>   wild west frontier mentality that we
>   have seen grow up around the iPhone,
>   iPod Touch, Google Android and the
>   Palm webOS.  At this time there will
>   be no independent software development
>   kit (SDK), although Microsoft does not
>   rule that out for down the road a
>   ways.

...and also [here](http://www.techflash.com/seattle/2009/09/zune_stops_squirting_and_adds_features_people_might_actually_use.html).

Comment: that was taken out of context. the next paragraph explains:

"Part of the reason behind this decision is because the Windows Mobile 7 team is currently working on an app store, and Microsoft did not want two separate teams working on essentially the same project, and eventually launching two versions of the same thing.  You can extrapolate from this nugget of information that the Zune HD will work with the Windows Mobile 7 app store, but that isn’t a certainty at this point."

You will be able to write Zune apps, just not yet. They need to finish polishing the app/store framework for release.

Answer (score 2):

Ever heard of **OpenZDK**?

> "That’s about to change. Through the work of myself as well as Netrix, Nurta, and the rest of the ZuneBoards Development Front, all Zune models, including the Zune HD, have been hacked. The first true hack available for the Zune, this makes it possible to, for the first time, run applications directly on top of the Zune firmware, with full access to everything XNA withheld before. The limitations of XNA are now no limitations at all."  (from Zune Boards: http://www.zuneboards.com/?p=vB50442)

The OpenZDK wiki: http://zunedevwiki.org/wiki/

Personal experience: I have used XNA games on the Zune HD along with the Zune 30...works great!